# Group list by month

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by, grouping

I have list with datetime objects. I would like to group by month and add it to the dictionary.

So after grouping process I want to have list per month and year. 
For example:
Before grouping
[mix below elements]

After grouping:
1) January 2015 - 5 elements
2) February 2015 - 2 elements
2) January 2014 - 2 elements

I have tried like this:

```
var test = this.myList.GroupBy(x => x.myDate.Month).ToList();
```

But iI thnink I need to use dictionary. Do you have any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: Not an answer, but based on your example you are also grouping based on the year rather than just the month.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Linq provides an option to convert your results into a dictionary:

```
myList.GroupBy(x => new {Month = x.myDate.Month, Year = x.myDate.Year})
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
```

Note that this will give you keys in form of `{Month=1,Year=2015}`. If you want a string instead, something like `January 2015`, you can use formatted date string as a key.

Comment: will this not combine the years?

Answer (score -1):

```
    myList
   .GroupBy(x => new {MonthYear = x.myDate.Month + "-" + x.myDate.Year})
   .Select(x => new { x.Key.MonthYear });
```